# Perform multiple unrelated operations in map function

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a list 'inputList' where I want to apply a method on each element, and add the result in another list 'outputList' and in another map 'outputMap'. Below are the 2 Operations

```
getEmployeeDetails(String employeeId)
```

and

```
getEmployeeSkills( String employeeId)
```

need to be performed for all elements of inputList.

When I use foreach as below , in this case I can do multiple operations

```
inputList.stream()
        .foreach ( elem -> 
              {
                outputList.add( employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(elem));       
                outputMap.put( elem, employeeRepository.getEmployeeSkills(elem);                                                                                       });
```

However, if I use recommended way of using map() function, then I am unable to perform both operations and able to perform only getEmployeeDetails() functions.

```
outputList = inputList.stream()
        .map(elem -> employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(elem))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
outputList = inputList.stream()
        .map(elem -> {
                        employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(elem));
                        outputMap.put( elem, employeeRepository.getEmployeeSkills(elem);    
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).collect(Collectors.toMap());
```

One more clarification is it is advisable to make database calls from stream? If not, what would be the better approach?

```
 inputList .stream()
        .foreach ( elem -> 
              {
                outputList.add( employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(elem));       
                outputMap.put( elem, employeeRepository.getEmployeeSkills(elem);     
                                                                                     });
```

Comment: "*`outputList = inputList.stream().forEach(...)`*" - This will not compile, [`forEach(...)` is a terminal operation, and returns `void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Comment: Fixed the code block.

Comment: "*... if I use recommended way of using map() function...*" - Who says that this is the recommended way? I do see nothing wrong with using `forEach(...)` (except, maybe, that I would remove the `stream()` since [each `Iterable` has a `forEach(...)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer))). I personally would just stream the list twice, once for each mapping, but that is just preference-based.

Comment: You can just write simple for loop.

Comment: @Turing85 1)  would be it be advisable to modify external collections from inside stream 2) will making database calls from stream of a list cause reduced performance  ?

Comment: You have to do something in a terminal `void` operation. Changing the state of anything is not really reactive, but it gets the job done. With respect to the database... a batch get would most probably perform better. How many entries are we talking?

Comment: @Turing85 in the range of 200-500 entries

Comment: Then I would advice to fetch the entities beforehand, through a single batch-call, and then operate on the fetched entities.

Comment: In that case, should the batch call involve data retrieval with SQL 'IN' keyword?

Comment: Different question. Depends on what exactly you are using (I am guessing spring-boot with a `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository`), and how the entity is structured. Simplest case: you have the ids, then just call `findAllById(...)`. For other cases, I recommend googling. If you want to write the actual sql to execute then yes, this would most probably invovle an `IN` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a map operation and collect two results into two different collections, so the `foreach` is already a good approach.

If you are concerned about performance you might be better off with a plain old `for` loop.

If your original list is the result of a database query probably you better do the join operation in a database query instead of performing an extra query for each entry in the list - but how to perform that is topic for another question (and needs other details to be included in the question anyways).

Comment: Unfortunately my repository is framework provided, so Joins degrade performance. So i went with for-each

Answer (score 0):

Joining should probably be done in your repository, so you can just fetch an employee with details and skills.

To answer your specific question how to do it with streams and map you can do something like this, you will still need an Employee wrapper class though. Here I assumed Employee would have a constructor that would take the id.

```java
input.stream()
        .map(Employee::new)
        .map(employee -> {
            employee.setSkills(getEmployeeSkills(employee.getId()));
            return employee;
        })
        .map(employee -> {
            employee.setDetails(getEmployeeDetails(employee.getId()));
            return employee;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Unfortunately my repository is framework provided, so Joins degrade performance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not really collecting the `outputMap` using the stream functionality, you *can* use map effectively for this purpose.

```
outputMap = new HashMap<String, Skills>();
outputList = inputList.stream()
    .map(elem -> {
       outputMap.put(elem, employeeRepository.getEmployeeSkills(elem));    
       return employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(elem));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is not beautiful to have a side effect in the stream like that, but it is simple to read, and I don't think you will get anything to run much faster.